# Force NSScrollView to use NSScrollerStyleOverlay independently from input device

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

How to force `NSScrollView` to use scrollers like that:

[image]

independently from input device, because now if computer has wired mouse connected or app is running on laptop (macbook) it uses scrollers like this:

[image]

witch is always visible. It is possible to achieve my desired result if user changes settings in system preferences. But I need to have that result without changing anything. Or maybe there is some easy method to use  custom `NSScrollers`?

Hiding scrollers would be pretty acceptable result, but when I hide them I have some scrolling issues. I use custom NSClipView witch adjusts documentView to be centered when adjusting its frame size. But when I adjust frame size, and it is scrolled to center, if I scroll anywhere it jumps to bottom left corner and then works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using table view and I just put this code in awakeFormNib:

```
[[self.tableView enclosingScrollView] setScrollerStyle:NSScrollerStyleOverlay];
```

I also tried to hide scrollers but then I couldn't scroll the content using trackpad (no problem using mouse). In the other project I have similar table view with the same settings and hiding scrollers doesn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notify:) name:NSPreferredScrollerStyleDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

- (void)notify:(NSNotification*)
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        weakself.scrollView.scrollerStyle = NSScrollerStyleOverlay;
    });
}
```